# python - sending hex string/packet to interface without IP

Tags: python, centos, hex, port, tcpreplay

I have a Centos machine that has two network interfaces, and I need to sent a hex String and force it to one of the interfaces.

I found the `socket.bind` and `socket.connect` methods, but the thing is - the destination I want to send the **hex string** to has no ip or port, its a TenGigaBit port on some machine that has no ip.

If it will help, I was able to send the a **pcap file** to the TenGigaBit port (no ip or port) with **tcpreplay**, like this:

```
tcpreplay --intf1=eth0 --cachefile=file.pcap
```

I want to be able to do the same, with a **hex String** (either in **python** or **tcpreplay**) and send a hex String.